# Perform calculation after checking if multiple variables exist

Tags: python

I am trying to do calculation on dataframe but I have an error. I check if variables exist and I do calculation with if statement. Any contribution would be appreciated.

My code:

```
trade = pd.read_excel('deribit4_5.xlsx', sheet_name='trade2')

''' option price '''
option = []
for x in trade['instrument_name'].drop_duplicates().sort_values():
  p = trade.loc[(trade['instrument_name']==x)]
  print(p)
  pp_sell = p.loc[p['direction']=='sell']
  pp_buy = p.loc[p['direction']=='buy']
  try:
    first_trade_sell = pp_sell.loc[pp_sell['trade_date']==min(pp_sell['trade_date'])].iloc[0]
    first_trade_buy = pp_buy.loc[pp_buy['trade_date']==min(pp_buy['trade_date'])].iloc[0]
  except:
    pass
  if first_trade_sell and first_trade_buy:
    mid_price = (first_trade_sell + first_trade_buy)/2
  elif first_trade_sell:
    mid_price = first_trade_sell
  else: 
    mid_price = first_trade_buy
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "deribit_histo.py", line 124, in <module>
    if first_trade_sell and first_trade_buy:
  File "/Users/delalma/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1556, in __nonzero__
    self.__class__.__name__
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: you're implying the problem is fully in python, but the error that's being raised is from pandas. Can you include a full code example?

Comment: you could also check if the var names are in locals()..if the variables don't exist, doing if var: will return an error

Comment: @RyanBaker I have updated the code

Answer (score 0):

I think the error itself is self-explanatory.

Let's take a sample dataframe :

```
df=pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,2],"b":[3,4]})
print(df)

   a  b
0  1  3
1  2  4
```

Now when I try to have an `if` condition on the first row :

```
if df.loc[0,:]:
    print("ok")
```

It throws this error

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. 
Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

**READ THE ERROR**

Now try using `.empty` instead :

```
if not df.loc[0,:].empty:
    print("ok")
```

And it works.